# Row-level-security dual join

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase

I have three tables

| journeys |
| --- |
| id |
| user_id |
| ... |

| sections |
| --- |
| id |
| journey_id |
| ... |

| stops |
| --- |
| id |
| section_id |
| ... |

I want to use row level security to make sure that a user can only insert a `stop` if the `uid()` matches the `user_id` on the `journey` that is referenced by the `stop` via `stops.section_id`->`sections.journey_id`->`journeys.user_id`.

In other words, the user should only be able to set `stops.section_id` to a `section` and thus to a `journey` that belongs to him.

How can I achieve this in Supabase with row level security joins?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an `EXISTS` condition:

```
CREATE POLICY may_insert_stop ON stops
FOR INSERT TO PUBLIC
WITH CHECK (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM journeys AS j
                       JOIN sections AS s ON s.journey_id = j.id
                    WHERE s.id = stops.section_id
                      AND j.user_id = uid()
                   )
           );
```