# Supabase/Postgres: Row Level Security (RLS) on a join table

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase

I have the following tables in a Supabase project:

```
users
--- 
id (uuid - ref auth.users.id)
```

```
workspaces
---
id (varchar)
```

```
user_workspaces
---
user_id
workspace_id
```

I want to set RLS on the join table, so that a User can only view any other User_workspace row that matches *any* Workspace the User belongs to.

What would this policy look like? TIA

Comment: I would mark this as a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71755619/6464308), but the answer received no upvotes.

Comment: I upvoted it, so it can be marked now